# Extract values if they are greater than a number but include smaller numbers if it is in series

Tags: r

I have a table something like below

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:20,
  Value = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3)
)
```

For values equal to 5 and 7 I would like to extract the precedent consecutive values if that makes sense.

Example output

```
  ID Value
1  1     2
2  2     3
3  3     4
4  4     5
5  11    1
6  12    2
7  13    3
8  14    4
9  15    5
10 16    6
11 17    7
```

I tried using for loop but couldn't manage to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One More Answer,

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:20,
  Value = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3)
)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(group = cumsum(lag(Value, 1, default = -Inf) %in% c(5,7))) %>% 
  filter(rev(cumprod(rev(c(diff(Value), 1) == 1))) & last(Value) %in% c(5,7)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>       ID Value
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1     2
#>  2     2     3
#>  3     3     4
#>  4     4     5
#>  5    11     1
#>  6    12     2
#>  7    13     3
#>  8    14     4
#>  9    15     5
#> 10    16     6
#> 11    17     7
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a dplyr-based solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  group_by(run = cumsum(
    lag(Value, default = -Inf) + 1 != Value
  )) |>
  filter(
    (5 %in% Value & Value <= 5) | 
    (7 %in% Value & Value <= 7)
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(!run)
```

Result:

```r
# A tibble: 11 × 2
      ID Value
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1     2
 2     2     3
 3     3     4
 4     4     5
 5    11     1
 6    12     2
 7    13     3
 8    14     4
 9    15     5
10    16     6
11    17     7
```

This finds and groups by consecutive runs; keeps only runs that include 5 or 7; and excludes values greater than 5 or 7, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` solution that should handle (not sure if needed ;-) ) larger amounts of values (stored in a vector `vec`) to filter on.

**solution 1**

```
library(data.table)
# values to check by group
vec <- c(5,7)
# split data to a list, based value decrease
L <- split(setDT(df), f = c(0,cumsum(diff(df$Value)<0)))
# split the data.table in groups, loop over these groups
# see in a value from vec is found in a group, select all values <= the max of the found value
lapply(L, function(x) if (length(intersect(vec, x$Value)) > 0) x[Value <= max(intersect(vec, x$Value)), ] else NULL) |> 
  rbindlist() # use rbindlist to put to rowbind to a single data.table again
```

**solution 2**

```
library(data.table)
vec <- c(5,7)
# create groups
setDT(df)[, group := c(0,cumsum(diff(Value)<0))]
# filter groups based on precense of value from vec, and use maximum present value to filter
df[, if(any(Value %in% vec)) .SD[Value <= max(intersect(vec, Value))], by = group]
```

**output**

```
#    ID Value
# 1:  1     2
# 2:  2     3
# 3:  3     4
# 4:  4     5
# 5: 11     1
# 6: 12     2
# 7: 13     3
# 8: 14     4
# 9: 15     5
#10: 16     6
#11: 17     7
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R use:

```
 subset(df, ave(Value %in% c(5,7), cumsum(c(1, diff(Value)) <= 0), FUN = any))
   ID Value
1   1     2
2   2     3
3   3     4
4   4     5
11 11     1
12 12     2
13 13     3
14 14     4
15 15     5
16 16     6
17 17     7
```

Comment: Works on provided sample data, but will not return desired output if a Value greater than 7 is present in a group.. check output of `df <- data.frame(ID = 1:20, Value = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3))`